# Problems with clone method in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I tried to clone one of my object today, but it seems that its not working like in documentation.

In my console I'm doing:

```
u = User.find 1
nu = u.clone
nu.new_record?
   => false 
nu.new?
  NoMethodError: undefined method `new?' for #<User:0x007fbf137b8278>
```

So it looks like cloned object is just a duplicate, because it has the same Id like old one, but according to documentation, it should be new object?

> clone()
>
> Returns a clone of the resource that hasn’t been assigned an id yet and is treated as a new resource.
>
> ryan = Person.find(1)
>
> not_ryan = ryan.clone
>
> not_ryan.new?  # => true

Comment: I tried the exact same sequence in the console and new_record? returned true.

Comment: Seems like it was removed from rails > 3.0.9

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/clone) is deprecated since Rails 2.3.8 and has probably been removed since. So in fact you are calling [Object#clone](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/clone) which used to call [ActiveRecord::Base#initialize_copy](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/initialize_copy) which was removed in Rails 3.0.9.

Use [dup](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/dup) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly gotcha for upgraders: calling 'clone' won't throw an error or anything - it'll just return the original model. So any code you wrote that's supposed to duplicate some model and make modifications to the new copy will instead silently modify the original!